# Python Program Not Reading in File

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to create a simple program that counts the number of lines, words, and characters in a file.  I can't seem to get the file to read in though, it returns the name of the file and not the contents of the file.  I have been passing the file name in on the command line without quotation marks.

```
print("This program will count the number of line, words, and characters in a file.")
user_in = input("Please enter a file to be counted: ")
infile = open(user_in, "r")


lc = 0
wc = 0
w_len = 0


for line in infile:
    usr_list = user_in.split(" ")
    print(usr_list)
    lc += 1
    for x in usr_list:
        w_len += len(x)
        wc += 1

#avg = w_len//wc
print("There were {} lines, {} words, and {} characters in your file.".format(lc, wc, w_len))

infile.close()
```

Comment: Looks like `usr_list = user_in.split(" ")` should be `usr_list = line.split(" ")` ?

Comment: Jon, thanks!  I can't believe I missed that.  Tired eyes and all that:)

Answer (score 1):

You're doing `usr_list = user_in.split(" ")` but it seems like you would like to do `usr_list = line.split(" ")`

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
usr_list = user_in.split(" ")
```

is splitting on the name of the file, not on the lines read in from the file.

What you should be doing is:

```
for line in infile:
    usr_list = line.split(" ")
```